# Reactjs ajax request not sending cookie

Tags: asp.net, ajax, reactjs, web, redux-thunk

React js not sending cookie, i am using react-redux thunk for sending request,

all requests are sent are not using the cookie session id.

because of missing session id, the server generate new cookie on each request and connot identify the user requests.

how can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Please add parameter `credentials: 'same-origin'` to your request,

Example request:

```
fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'same-origin', //This was added
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }})
```

Comment: This did not help

Comment: whats is your request?